# Terraform: How to start counting from a particular Number (instead of 0)?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Regarding to the Docs (https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count), counting with Terraform starts at `0`.

```
variable "vm_count" {
  type = number
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "vmdeployment" {

  count                      = var.vm_count
  name                       = "cmw-${var.service_name}-${format("%04d", count.index)}"
```

How can I define a different starting point when using `[count.index]` to deploy multiple VM-Instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with for_each.

First, I create a Variable

**terraform.tfvars**

```
vm_list          = [1,2,3]
service_name     = "foobar"
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "vm_list" {
  type = list(any)
}
variable "service_name" {
  type = string
}
```

**And finally my main.tf**

```
  for_each   = { for i in var.vm_list : "key_${i}" => i }
  name       = "vm-${var.service_name}-${format("%04d", each.value)}"
```

Answer (score 3):

`count.index` [will always start with 0](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count).

If you want your VM names to start with another number, `1` for example, just use some math:

```
name = "cmw-${var.service_name}-${format("%04d", count.index + 1)}"
```

---

Alternatively, you could use [the Terraform range function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/range), to create a list of a specific range of numbers, and then use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each) instead of `count` in your resource definition.